# pgfplots - box plots min and max x-values

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

Im using the following code from pgfplots to create box plots:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [
    ytick={1},
    yticklabels={},
    y=0.7cm
  ]  
  \addplot+[boxplot]
    table[row sep=\\, y index = 0] {
    data\\
      2\\ 2\\ 3\\ 3\\ 4\\ 4\\ 4\\ 4 \\
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This produced a box plot like **first** one in the following picture:

[image: box plots, first on is the actual one, second is how i would like it to look]

In the first box plot it appears as if my data was on a scale from 2 to 4, since all of my results are in that range. The actual range for the data was from 0 to 6. Therefore i would like to show that in the box plot. This is shown in the **second** box plot in the picture.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `xmin` and `xmax` values:

```
\documentclass[png,tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}% version
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [
    ytick={1},
    yticklabels={},
    y=0.7cm,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=6,
  ]  
  \addplot+[boxplot]
    table[row sep=\\, y index = 0] {
    data\\
      2\\ 2\\ 3\\ 3\\ 4\\ 4\\ 4\\ 4 \\
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

In order to still display the x ticks 2.5 and 3.5, one might exploit the `extra x ticks` key:

```
\documentclass[png,tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}% version
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [
    ytick={1},
    yticklabels={},
    extra x ticks={2.5,3.5},
    y=0.7cm,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=6,
  ]  
  \addplot+[boxplot]
    table[row sep=\\, y index = 0] {
    data\\
      2\\ 2\\ 3\\ 3\\ 4\\ 4\\ 4\\ 4 \\
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

but IMHO it is better to keep the previous version or to switch completely to a finer scale, i.e 0.5.